# How to split text into chunks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, paging, pager

I am trying to split a chunk of text into equal parts so I can do a pager plugin for the text. I want to be able to apply the plugin to a container div without having to specify children like in some other pager plugins; so it could be used with a CMS like Wordpress.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

All plugins I have found so far use child nodes so split the content eg.

```
<div class="container">
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

If I have a set height for the container with overflow:hidden applied with CSS, I am having trouble finding the split points due to the content being inline.

Ideally, I am hoping to split the text into chunks, then create a pager nav beneath the text area - all because the client dislikes scrolling (yes, we're still at that stage in 2011).

Any help with how to approach this will be much appreciated.

Am I even approaching this in the best way, looking to split the content? It's vital that that container has simple markup in it so I can add the_content() from Wordpress.

Comment: do you mean [wordwrap](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wordWrap) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Columnizer Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) source and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Good call on the columnizer. I could split it within a container and then scroll it or page it. Brilliant thanks!